# How to notice parent object that child objects have been changed?

Tags: php, design-patterns

If i need to make the object knoW about its state change, i make all properties private and add setters and getters for them.

What about if object's property is another object.
I can get it by link with get method, change it, and parent object won't know about it.

I suppose it is a regular problem and it should have a traditional solution. What pattern should I read about?

Actually the child object has another object to, and i want to notify the main parent. Recursively

Comment: Why would a base object care that an extended object has changed? Can you give us a use case so we can understand the issue better?

Comment: OriginalCart [(array) CartItems]; CartItem [(int) product_id, (int) price, (int) amount]; Order ((object) OriginalCart, (array) PromoMechanics, (object) ComputedOrder); ////
Someone can get OriginalCart and change it (Change CartItems).
I need to destroy ComputedOrder inside the Order and make a new one.

Comment: Let me know if you need more precisions from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to this problem is to only allow children mutations through the root entity, which means you ideally wouldn't expose accessors to retrieve children and if you do, you'd return copies to preserve encapsulation. This approach usually aligns very well with a behavior-rich domain model.

However, if you are modeling large graph-like structures then the above-mentioned approach may not be very practical. In that case you could rely on an implementation of the [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or any of it's variants.

Please note that modeling very large root entities is often a code smell that might lead to performance issues & concurrency conflicts. The root entity should only be as large as it needs to be to protect business invariants.